# Create a factory that doesn't return anything - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

## Intro

Hello everyone,

Recently I've picked Laravel and I'm still learning about the framework (which by the way I find amazing).

I'm working on a project in where i have a model called Order which I use for grouping other Order models (for example ClassicOrder, InstantOrder etc...) by using a one-to-one morph relationship.

The Orders table store an id, an order_id and the order_type which is used for the morph relationship.

## The Problem

I've made a factory for each Order type and now I want to create a factory that generates n orders by randomly picking between all the order types.

I've done it like this:

```
$factory->define(Order::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  $className = collect(Order::getModels())->random();
  $order = factory($className)->create();
    return [
        'order_id' => $order->id,
        'type' => get_class($order)
    ];
});
```

Now, this is working but the problem is that each order use a trait called Order which already register the order in the orders table so when I call the factory I'll get two rows in the order table for the same order.
This is the order trait:

```
Trait Order {
    public static function boot()
    {
      parent::boot();
      self::created(function ($model) {
          // Add the order to the orders table to give him a public id
          DB::table('orders')->insert(['order_id' => $model->id, 'type' => self::class]);

          // Set and create the order path if the order isn't instant
          if (!is_a($model, 'App\InstantOrder')) {
              $orderType = explode('\\', get_class($model))[1]; // App\OrderType -> OrderType
              $folderName = $orderType . '_' . $model->publicId . '_' . time() . '/';
              $model->path = public_path() . '/storage/orders/' . $folderName;
              $model->save();
              File::makeDirectory($model->path, 0777, true);
          }
      });

      self::creating(function ($model) {
          $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
      });
    }
}
```

I can avoid this by calling factory()->make() instead of factory->create() but this doesn't seem right to me.

## The Question

I've thought about some solutions and I've come out with the followings:
 - Don't make the factory return anything, but looks like I can't.
 - Delete the inserted rows before returning the data to store in the Orders table, and even if not really great, it looks like the only solution.

**Can I make a factory without returning anything?**

Thanks and wish a great day to everyone.

-Riccardo

Comment: This is a well written question, welcome to StackOverflow :-) The problem is here "[...] the problem is that each order use a trait called Order which already register the order in the orders table [...]". You should not do this, can you post the code referenced here so we can review it and explain the correct way to accomplish what you're trying to achieve. The problem isn't with factories, it's with your non-standard approach to creating models.

Comment: @sam Thanks for the fast response! I've inserted the Order trait code, let me know if you need anything more

Comment: Although not always the case, as a general rule you should not use events to perform further inserts, it creates a very inflexible codebase which causes problems like this. Morphable types are intended for many to many relationships, meaning a single item _does not_ have a single relationship, whereas in your system an order has a single type of order. I'm running out of characters so I'll continue in another comment...

Comment: Because each Order has a single type of Order (unless I've misunderstood your architecture; correct me if I'm wrong) you can simply store the order type on the `Order`, e.g: `['type' => 'instant', 'id' => 1]` then you'd be able to use Factories in the documented way, and you won't need to use events for further inserts. You would create your instant order (e.g: `$instant = InstantOrder::create([])`) then you would add it as an Order, e.g: `Order::create(['type' => 'instant', 'id' => $instant->id]);`

Comment: @sam Thanks! Now I understand better when I should use morphable. Since I'm new to stack overflow is there any "upvote" I can give to you?

Comment: being able to make a positive contribution is all I desire, no need for any points :)

Comment: @sam Having (good) answers to vote on isn't purely about acknowledging the authors contribution. It is an instrument to determine good questions and answers within a jungle of basically everything from good to unsalvageable. So please provide an answer, it might help future readers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well lemme first welcome you, and then ask who said it wasn't a a good idea to make a factory that return anything, as it's mentioned in Laravel docs that's how it's written:-

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

As mentioned [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#writing-factories)

And then you can use it in Model factories as mentioned [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding#using-model-factories)

I guess that's best practice as the Documentation says i guess.

And this is also a quick intro that you should check out for seeding data with [Relationships](https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-two-ways-seed-data-relationships/)